# kNN classifier memory error when creating meshgrid

Tags: python

```
# Import all of the 
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import statistics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from dtreeviz.trees import *

# Set some lists to store the IMU data.

time_track = []
ax_set = []
ay_set = []
az_set = []

gx_set = []
gy_set = []
gz_set = []

activity_set = []

#####################################################
# map_activity(activity_string)
#
# A simple function that maps the activity description
# string from the VoTT data file to a integer value
# that will be used by the machine learning workflow.
#
#####################################################

def map_activity(activity_string):
    if activity_string == 'Standing':
        return 0
    elif activity_string == 'Walking':
        return 1
    elif activity_string == 'Jogging':
        return 2
    elif activity_string == 'Side-Step':
        return 3
    elif activity_string == 'Running':
        return 4
#    elif activity_string == 'High_knees':
#        return 5
with open('a3_imu_data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        #print(row)
        time_track.append(float(row[0]));
        ax_set.append(float(row[1]));
        ay_set.append(float(row[2]));
        az_set.append(float(row[3]));
        gx_set.append(float(row[4]));
        gy_set.append(float(row[5]));
        gz_set.append(float(row[6]));
        
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20,10))
axs[0].plot(ax_set, color='r')
axs[0].plot(ay_set, color='g')
axs[0].plot(az_set, color='b')

axs[1].plot(gx_set, color='r')
axs[1].plot(gy_set, color='g')
axs[1].plot(gz_set, color='b')

start_idx = 800

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20,10))
axs[0].plot(ax_set[start_idx:370000], color='r')
axs[0].plot(ay_set[start_idx:370000], color='g')
axs[0].plot(az_set[start_idx:370000], color='b')

axs[1].plot(gx_set[start_idx:370000], color='r')
axs[1].plot(gy_set[start_idx:370000], color='g')
axs[1].plot(gz_set[start_idx:370000], color='b')

#Now we need to find the end point
start_ts = time_track[start_idx];
print(start_ts)

# The video has been cut to 443 seconds in length - need to find 
# Start_ts + 443 seconds. This should land us at the end point
# We can sanity check this by inspecting the plot

end_idx = time_track.index(start_ts+712)

# Sanity Check
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20,10))
axs[0].plot(ax_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='r')
axs[0].plot(ay_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='g')
axs[0].plot(az_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='b')

axs[1].plot(gx_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='r')
axs[1].plot(gy_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='g')
axs[1].plot(gz_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='b')

with open('a3_activity_annotations.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        time_Stamp = (row[0].split('='))[1]
        activity_set.append([float(time_Stamp),row[-1], map_activity(row[-1])])
        
# Now we can create an activity time track for each data point within
# the imu timeseries. We will have a list to store the numeric code and the string.
activity_timeseries = [];
activity_string_timeseries = [];
activity_idx = 0;

# We need the time stamp for the start point
start_time = time_track[start_idx]

# The time track segment we are interested in 
time_track_segment = time_track[start_idx:end_idx]

#Add an 'end' activity - this book-ends the data
activity_set.append([time_track_segment[-1]-start_time, 'Standing'])

# Zero out the time track segment to make it match the video time
time_track_segment = np.array(time_track_segment)-start_time

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.plot(time_track_segment,ax_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='r')
ax.plot(time_track_segment,ay_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='g')
ax.plot(time_track_segment,az_set[start_idx:end_idx], color='b')


for imu_time_track_item in time_track_segment:
    current_time =  imu_time_track_item
    next_activity_ts = activity_set[activity_idx+1][0]
    
    # Here we need to move to the next activity in the annotations data if the current
    # IMU data point lies after the next annotation time stamp.
    if current_time > next_activity_ts:
        #Move to nex activity
        activity_idx = activity_idx + 1;
        next_activity_ts = activity_set[activity_idx+1][0]
    
    
    activity_timeseries.append(activity_set[activity_idx][2])
    activity_string_timeseries.append(activity_set[activity_idx][1])

# Plot the location of the activity transitions just to sanity check the data
for act in np.array(list(zip(*activity_set)))[0,:]:
    ax.axvline(float(act))
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.hist(activity_timeseries,bins=[-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5])

#We are only interested in the video window
ax_set = ax_set[start_idx:end_idx]
ay_set = ay_set[start_idx:end_idx]
az_set = az_set[start_idx:end_idx]
gx_set = gx_set[start_idx:end_idx]
gy_set = gy_set[start_idx:end_idx]
gz_set = gz_set[start_idx:end_idx]

# Now we can start working on the machine learning workflow.
# The first step is to calculate some feature that we can use.
# We will base our analysis around a moving window across the
# the timeseries data. This involves taking a fixed length window, based upon the time, and
# sliding it across the data.
# To keep thing simple, we will start with a 1 second window with no overlapping
# data points

feature_set = []
target_set  = []            
window_size = 1.0;            

for t in range(int(time_track_segment[0]),int(time_track_segment[-1])):
    
    #There is a missing data-point (probably due to a bad segment on the SD card)
    if t == 104 or t == 105 or t == 163 or t == 164 or t == 274 or t == 275 :
        continue
    
    #The index function finds the index of the first occurnace of the data
    window_start_idx = list(time_track_segment).index(t)
    window_end_idx = list(time_track_segment).index(t+window_size)
    ax_window = ax_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]
    ay_window = ay_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]
    az_window = az_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]
    gx_window = gx_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]
    gy_window = gy_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]
    gz_window = gz_set[window_start_idx:window_end_idx]

    #activity that will be assigned to the set of features
    activity_code = activity_timeseries[window_start_idx]

    # Now we can build features from the data window
    # Mean
    mu_ax = statistics.mean(ax_window)
    mu_ay = statistics.mean(ay_window)
    mu_az = statistics.mean(az_window)
    mu_gx = statistics.mean(gx_window)
    mu_gy = statistics.mean(gy_window)
    mu_gz = statistics.mean(gz_window)
    
    # Max
    max_ax = max(ax_window)
    max_ay = max(ay_window)
    max_az = max(az_window)
    max_gx = max(gx_window)
    max_gy = max(gy_window)
    max_gz = max(gz_window)
    
    # Min
    min_ax = min(ax_window)
    min_ay = min(ay_window)
    min_az = min(az_window)
    min_gx = min(gx_window)
    min_gy = min(gy_window)
    min_gz = min(gz_window)
    
    ax_abs_sum = 0
    ay_abs_sum = 0
    az_abs_sum = 0
    
    gx_abs_sum = 0
    gy_abs_sum = 0
    gz_abs_sum = 0
    
    a_sum_sq = 0
    g_sum_sq = 0
    
    # Here we need to accumulate the values to calculate the SMA and AI
    for i in range(0, len(ax_window)):
        
        # Add up the absolute values for the SMA
        ax_abs_sum = ax_abs_sum + abs(ax_window[i])
        ay_abs_sum = ay_abs_sum + abs(ay_window[i])
        az_abs_sum = az_abs_sum + abs(az_window[i])
        
        gx_abs_sum = gx_abs_sum + abs(gx_window[i])
        gy_abs_sum = gy_abs_sum + abs(gy_window[i])
        gz_abs_sum = gz_abs_sum + abs(gz_window[i])
        
        
        a_sum_sq = ((ax_window[i]**2) + (ay_window[i]**2) + (az_window[i]**2)) + a_sum_sq
        g_sum_sq = ((gx_window[i]**2) + (gy_window[i]**2) + (gz_window[i]**2)) + g_sum_sq
    
    # Signal Magnitude area    
    a_sma = (ax_abs_sum + ay_abs_sum + az_abs_sum) / len(ax_window)
    g_sma = (gx_abs_sum + gy_abs_sum + gz_abs_sum) / len(ax_window)

    # Average intensity
    a_av_intensity = math.sqrt(a_sum_sq) / len(ax_window)
    g_av_intensity = math.sqrt(g_sum_sq) / len(ax_window)


    feature_row = [mu_ax, mu_ay, mu_az, mu_gx, mu_gy, mu_gz, \
                   max_ax, max_ay, max_az, max_gx, max_gy, max_gz, \
                   min_ax, min_ay, min_az, min_gx, min_gy, min_gz, \
                   a_sma, g_sma, a_av_intensity, g_av_intensity]

    feature_set.append(feature_row)
    target_set.append(activity_code)

# Lets visualise some of the features just out of interest - we will look at the SMA and AI

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.plot(range(1,706),np.array(feature_set)[:,18], color='r')
ax.plot(range(1,706),np.array(feature_set)[:,19], color='g')
ax.plot(range(1,706),np.array(feature_set)[:,20], color='b')
ax.plot(range(1,706),np.array(feature_set)[:,21], color='c')

# Plot the location of the activity transitions just to sanity check the data
for act in np.array(list(zip(*activity_set)))[0,:]:
    ax.axvline(float(act), alpha=0.5)
    
###################################################
#
#KNN Classifier
#
####################################    
    
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X = np.array(feature_set)
y = np.array(target_set)


# Split the data into a training set and a test set
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ???

#Solution - I have explicitly strafified this set as well:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify = y)

#We need to store the best performance and the features that achieved them.
best_mean_f1 = 0
best_f1 = 0
best_f2 = 0

# We will be testing every combination of pairs of features 

for f1 in range(0,22):
    for f2 in range(0,22):
        
        # We want 2 features, not 1
        if f1 == f2:
            continue
        
        features_idx_to_use = [f1,f2]
        
        clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
        clf.fit(X_train[:,features_idx_to_use], y_train)
        
        # Return the predictions for the 3-Fold crossvalidation
        y_predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, X_train[:,features_idx_to_use],y_train, cv=3)
        
        # Construct the confusion matricies
        conf_mat_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_predicted)
        
        # Print out the recall, precision and F1 scores
        # There will be a value for each class
        # CV Train
        print("CV Train:",f1,":",f2," - ", recall_score(y_train,y_predicted,average=None))
        print("CV Train:",f1,":",f2," - ",precision_score(y_train,y_predicted,average=None))
        print("CV Train:",f1,":",f2," - ",f1_score(y_train,y_predicted,average=None, labels=np.unique(y_predicted)))

        current_f1 = np.mean(f1_score(y_train,y_predicted,average=None))
        if current_f1 > best_mean_f1:
            best_f1 = f1
            best_f2 = f2
            best_mean_f1 = current_f1
            best_clf = clf
            
print("best f1 :", best_f1)
print("best f2 :", best_f2)
            
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.scatter(X_train[:,best_f1], X_train[:,best_f2], c=y_train, cmap='rainbow', alpha=0.3, s=30)

# Now we need to test our classifier using the test set.



y_test_predicted = best_clf.predict(X_test[:,[best_f1, best_f2]])
conf_mat_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_predicted)

# Test
print("Test Recall:",recall_score(y_test,y_test_predicted,average=None))
print("Test Precision:",precision_score(y_test,y_test_predicted,average=None))
print("Test F1 Score:",f1_score(y_test,y_test_predicted,average=None, labels=np.unique(y_predicted)))

# Plot the confusion matrices using the pretty functions
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(best_clf, X_train[:,[best_f1, best_f2]], y_train,
                                 #display_labels=['Standing', 'Walking','Jogging', 'Side Step','Running','High Knees'],
                                 display_labels=['Standing', 'Walking','Jogging', 'Side-Step','Running'],
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,ax=ax)
# Rotate the labels so they can be read
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(45)

ax.set_title('3-Fold Training')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(best_clf, X_test[:,[best_f1, best_f2]], y_test,
                                 #display_labels=['Standing', 'Walking','Jogging', 'Side Step','Running','High Knees'],
                                 display_labels=['Standing', 'Walking','Jogging', 'Side-Step','Running'],
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,ax=ax)
# Rotate the labels so they can be read
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(45)

ax.set_title('testing')
        

# Class names - I used a dictionary structure because the dtreeviz module was playing up with a list
#c_names = {0:"Standing", 1:"Walking", 2:"Jogging", 3:"Side-Step", 4:"Running", 5:"High-Knees"}
c_names = {0:"Standing", 1:"Walking", 2:"Jogging", 3:"Side-Step", 4:"Running"}
# Feature names for the tree.
f_names = ["Mean Ax", "Mean Ay", "Mean Az","Mean Gx", "Mean Gy", "Mean Gz",
           "Max Ax", "Max Ay", "Max Az","Max Gx", "Max Gy", "Max Gz", 
           "Min Ax", "Min Ay", "Min Az","Min Gx", "Min Gy", "Min Gz",
           "Acceleration SMA", "Gyroscope SMA" , "Acceleration AI", "Gyroscope AI"]


nclasses = len(c_names)

y_score = best_clf.predict_proba(X_test[:,[best_f1, best_f2]])

# We need to format the y_test into a n_samples x 3 binary array
# that indicates class membership
y_test_bin = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
#y_test_bin = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[c_names])
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(nclasses):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test_bin[:,i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

print("AUC:", roc_auc)

# Plot the TPR vs FPR for each class
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
#colors = ['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue']
colors = ['green', 'orange', 'deeppink', 'yellow', 'grey']
for i, color in zip(range(nclasses), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color,
             label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
ax.set_xlim([0.0, 1.0])
ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])
ax.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate')
ax.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate')
ax.set_title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
ax.legend(loc="lower right")

h = .02  # step size in the mesh
# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X_test[:, best_f1].min() - 1, X_test[:, best_f1].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X_test[:, best_f2].min() - 1, X_test[:, best_f2].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
Z = best_clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
cs = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z,cmap=plt.get_cmap('Pastel2'))
#cs = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, colors = colors)


# Plot also the training points
for i, color in zip(best_clf.classes_, colors):
    idx = np.where(y_test == i)
    #ax.scatter(X_test[idx, best_f1], X_test[idx, best_f2], c=color, label=c_names[i],
     #           cmap=plt.get_cmap('brg'), edgecolor='black', s=20)
    ax.scatter(X_test[idx, best_f1], X_test[idx, best_f2], c=color, label=c_names[i], edgecolor='black', s=50)
plt.title("kNN Classifier")
plt.axis('tight')

# Plot the three one-against-all classifiers
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
coef = best_clf.coef_
intercept = best_clf.intercept_

# Lets make a function to plot the hyperplanes used by the SVM for 
# Classification.

def plot_hyperplane(c, color):
    def line(x0):
        return (-(x0 * coef[c, 0]) - intercept[c]) / coef[c, 1]

    plt.plot([xmin, xmax], [line(xmin), line(xmax)],
              ls="--", color=color)

plot_hyperplane(0, "green")
plot_hyperplane(1, "orange")
plot_hyperplane(2, "deeppink")
plot_hyperplane(3, "yellow")
plot_hyperplane(4, "grey")
```

The error is
File "C:\Users\bugzoid\Documents\Study\COSC102\Assignment 3\assignment03.py", line 429, in 
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in meshgrid

File "C:\Users\bugzoid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4301, in meshgrid
output = [x.copy() for x in output]

File "C:\Users\bugzoid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4301, in 
output = [x.copy() for x in output]

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 6.25 TiB for an array with shape (1158550, 741800) and data type float64

I thought I fixed it by only selecting the best two features of the dataset but it still throws a memoryerror.

Comment: Seems like `x` is too large to call `x.copy()`

Comment: I solved it by increasing the step size to 4